# Delete N lines after cursor that contain a specific pattern

Tags: command-line

It is possible to delete all lines matching a pattern using  `:g/pattern/d`.

Using the following command, you can replace words matching a pattern, 20 lines after where the cursor currently is: `:s/pattern/changed_pattern/g20`

How do you delete all lines matching a pattern, but N lines after where the cursor currently is ?

I've tried : `34,50/pattern/d` however it delete backward, and inconsistently. Beside, it requires you to know exactly the lines between which to apply the deletion.

Comment: Can you please provide a short example input with the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "backward" and "inconsistently"? An example of what you're seeing and what you expected might help...

Answer (score 1):

These commands should do the trick

```
:global/pattern/.+1,.+Ndelete
:global/pattern/\/+1,\/+Ndelete
```

The key is to understand [range] for `delete` command.

- `.+1` one line after cursor line
- `.+N` N lines after cursor line
- `\/+1` one line after current match
- `\/+N` N lines after current match

See `:help cmdline-ranges` for more details.

Be aware it will delete pattern if it is in N lines range!